# Write to file from string and array

Tags: csv, f#

I'm trying to write an csv file where some of the values comes from arrays.

```
    let handle = "thetitle"
    let title  = "The Title"
    let body = "ipsum lorem"
    let mutable variantPrice = [|1000,2000,3000,4000|]
    let mutable variantComparePrice = [|2000,4000,6000,8000|]
    let mutable storlek = ["50x50","50x60","50x70","50x80"]

    let Header = [|
                  (handle, title, body,variantPrice, variantComparePrice, storlek)
                 |]

    let lines = Header |> Array.map (fun (h, t, vp,vcp,b,s) -> sprintf "Handle\tTitle\tStorlek\tVariantPrice\tVariantComparePrice\tBody\n %s\t%s\t%s\t%s"h t s vp vcp b)

File.WriteAllLines( "data\\test.csv", lines, Encoding.UTF8)
```

But the problem is that the expression in lines are expected string but im sending in string[]

```
Ideal would be that the csv file looked something like this

|handle|title|body|variantPrice|variantComparePrice|storlek|
|thetitle|The Title|ipsum lorem|1000|2000|50x50|
|thetitle|         |           |2000|4000|50x60|
|thetitle|         |           |3000|6000|50x70|
|thetitle|         |           |4000|8000|50x80|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that your variables storing data like `variantPrice` are currently arrays containing just a single element, which is a tuple - this is because you've separated elements using `,` rather than `;`. Most likely, you'll want something like:

```
let variantPrice = [|1000;2000;3000;4000|]
let variantComparePrice = [|2000;4000;6000;8000|]
let storlek = [|"50x50";"50x60";"50x70";"50x80"|]
```

With this, you can then use `Array.zip3` to get a single array with all the data (one item per row).

```
let data = Array.zip3 variantPrice variantComparePrice storlek
```

Now you can use `Array.map` to format the individual lines. The following is my guess based on your sample:

```
let lines = data |> Array.map (fun (vp, vcp, s) ->
  sprintf "|%s| | |%d|%d|%s" handle vp vcp s)
```

This is an array of lines represented as strings. Finally, you can append the header to the lines and write this to a file:

```
let header = "|handle|title|body|variantPrice|variantComparePrice|storlek|"
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:/temp/test.csv", 
  Array.append [| header |] lines, Encoding.UTF8)
```

Comment: Thank you! Array.zip3 will come in hand in this project!